# how to compute the max/min eigenvalue of a special matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I am stuck on computing the max and min eigenvalue for the following matrixes:

1. 2 * (1 - e$\lambda$) * I @ e * ($X^T\Omega X$),

where X is of shape(n, d), $\Omega$ is of shape(n, n) and is a diagonal matrix, @ is matmul, * is elementwise mul, e is sufficiently small, $\lambda$ > 0, I is identity of shape(d, d), the diagonal terms in $\Omega$ is in range(0, 0.5^2).

2. e^2 * $X^T\Omega^2 X$, the same rule as above.

Is there anything I can say about an upper bound for e, if the eigenvalues of the sum of the two above equations is in the range(0, 1).

Comment: It looks like your first expression is just 
$$
2(1 - \epsilon \lambda) I \epsilon (X^T\Omega X).
$$
Should the $I$ be inside of the parentheses instead?  That is, should we have
$$
2(1 - \epsilon \lambda I)\cdot \epsilon (X^T\Omega X)?
$$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, Hi, I am making the first part 2(1 - $\epsilon \lambda$) element-wise multiply by the Identity matrix so that it becomes a (d, d) shape matrix and then we can do the matrix multiplication with the second part, $\epsilon (X^T\Omega X)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sum of the two matrices is given by
$$
2\epsilon (1 - \lambda \epsilon)(X^T\Omega X) + 
\epsilon^2 X^T \Omega^2 X = \\
X^T[2\epsilon(1 - \lambda \epsilon)\Omega + \epsilon^2 \Omega^2]X.
$$
The eigenvalues of the matrix between the parentheses, i.e. the eigenvalues of 
$$
M = 2\epsilon(1 - \lambda \epsilon)\Omega + \epsilon^2 \Omega^2
$$
are equal to $2\epsilon(1 - \lambda \epsilon)d_i + \epsilon^2 d_i$, where $d_1,\dots,d_n$ are the diagonal entries of $\Omega$.  The largest possible eigenvalue for $d_i$ is $(0.5)^2 = 1/4$, so the largest possible eigenvalue for $M$ is 
$$
c = 2\epsilon(1 - \lambda \epsilon)\cdot \frac 14 + \epsilon^2 (\frac 14)^2.
$$
Now, it can be shown that maximum eigenvalue of $X^T\Omega X$ is at most equal to the maximum eigenvalue of $X^TX$ times the maximal eigenvalue of $\Omega$.

If $k$ denotes the maximal eigenvalue of $X^TX$, then you are looking for a value of $\epsilon$ for which $c \cdot k < 1$. Expanding the equation $c\cdot k = 1$ in terms of $\epsilon$ gives you a quadratic equation that can be solved for $\epsilon$ to give you the desired upper bound.